# What are recommended ocr library's in android?

Tags: android, ocr

Please provide some recommended  ocr library's for android which we can integrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some paid and free library's available ,

1) Google vision API (paid)

2) http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android (paid service)

3) https://github.com/tesseract-ocr (free)

Comment: https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY's Android OCR lib : http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android

Tesseract JNI wrapper : http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/68

Answer (score 0):

Look at

1) ABBYY's Android OCR lib (paid) -https://www.abbyy.com/en-apac/mobile-ocr/android-ocr/

2) Tesseract JNI wrapper (free) - https://github.com/tesseract-ocr

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Tesseract open source OCR.

Tutorial : http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/
Sample : https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

Answer (score 0):

The best library that is lightweight with a good accuracy rate is Google's [Mobile Vision Text API](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0). It has a well described tutorial on Google codelabs that you can read to give it a try. It also supports Live Detection.

Comment: Is it a free service or is it same as Google vision API which that is a paid service ?